# Image won't show in Chrome or Safari when hosted

Tags: html, css

When I host the following code on my computer and load it in Chrome the top left logo shows just fine. When I try and host it from my site Chrome reserves the correct container size but no image and Safari reserves a massive image size and no image. What am I missing here?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-custom p-1 mb-2">
        <img id="head-img" src="Retirement-Solutions-4u-Final-logo.jpg" alt="Retirement-Solutions-4U-Final-logo">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a> <!--This needs to be something besides Blog-->
                    </li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link head-phone mr-auto justify-content: right" href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> 888-218-0324</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#head-img{
    width: 60vh;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Link to page: http://base-campmarketing.com

Comment: got a 404 for http://base-campmarketing.com/Retirement-Solutions-4u-Final-logo.jpg - does the image exist? does the it has rights for public to view?

Comment: CORS related? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is incorrect. It's supposed to have a capital "U". The "alt" attribute on the logo had the correct file name in the HTML source. Once the logo shows up the issue should be fixed on Safari too.

Wrong name:

```
http://base-campmarketing.com/Retirement-Solutions-4u-Final-logo.jpg
```

Right name:

```
http://base-campmarketing.com/Retirement-Solutions-4U-Final-logo.jpg
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Comment: @TylerMason You're welcome. If you found this answer helpful please give it an upvote and mark it as the correct answer.